# Deployment behaviour on Vercel

Tags: vercel

When pushing to main branch, vercel automatically creates a deployment with a random subdomain.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour and only push to production, to a specific domain? What about the preview deployments?

Comment: https://vercel.com/knowledge/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: All deploys have unique URLs. But also there's a single production URL.**

You can have simultaneous versions (each with unique subdomain) but when a deploy is successful, it automatically updates the production URL.

For example:

1. **You make your first deploy**
2. Vercel provides you this link, with a random subdomain: [project-random001.vercel.app](https://vercel.com/docs)
3. Vercel ALSO provides a clean production URL for the SAME page: [project.vercel.app](https://vercel.com/docs)
4. **You make a second deploy**
5. Vercel provides you yet another link, with a random subdomain: [project-randomsub002.vercel](https://vercel.com/docs).
6. Vercel updates environment, keeping the same url ([project.vercel.app](https://vercel.com/docs)).

So your production URL has always the newest version, while each deploy has unique URLs.